# "Install Error" when uploading App with Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Here is the error I'm getting:

> Resolver: Install error - slf4j.log4j12 Exception's name: java.io.IOException, Exception's message: Error accessing file:/Volumes/HD/.itmstransporter/obr/1.9.8/slf4j.log4j12-1.7.25.jar

[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you tried to repeat the upload? Seems like a temporary problem with Apple server service which is handle by Java. It has nothing to do with Swift.

Comment: I tried 5 times so I’ll wait and try again tomorrow. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try:

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
```